# Can a Magus combine a Whirlwind Attack with Spellstrike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

Can a Magus use Whirlwind attack to deliver a spell to multiple opponents with Spell strike?

And secondly, Is Whirlwind Attack even worth taking if it can't do the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It depends on the spell.

From the Magus rules on [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus) (*emphasis mine*):

> **Spellstrike**
>
> At 2nd level, whenever a magus casts a spell with a range of “touch” from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon he is wielding as part of a melee attack. Instead of the free melee touch attack normally allowed to deliver the spell, a magus can make *one free melee attack with his weapon (at his highest base attack bonus) as part of casting this spell*. If successful, this melee attack deals its normal damage as well as the effects of the spell. ...

Spellstrike is a free action that is considered part of the action used to cast the spell.

From the Whirlwind Attack feat on [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/whirlwind-attack-combat-final/) (*emphasis mine*):

> When you use the *full-attack action*, you can give up your regular attacks and instead make one melee attack at your highest base attack bonus against each opponent within reach. You must make a separate attack roll against each opponent.
>
> When you use the Whirlwind Attack feat, *you also forfeit any bonus or extra attacks granted by other feats, spells, or abilities.*

Whirlwind Attack is a full-attack action. You can't replace the free attack from Spellstrike with a full-attack. Whirlwind Attack also **explicitly** says that you give up any other attacks you might have from other sources.

However, some touch attack spells grant multiple charges (for example, [Chill Touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chill-touch/)). While the free attack you get when you cast the spell initially cannot be turned into a whirlwind attack, you **can** use any remaining touch charges during a later whirlwind attack.

Note that this still may not be a worthwhile combination, simply because Whirlwind Attack has a lot of prerequisites that are not particularly useful, and only pays off when you're adjacent to several foes (which is not normally a safe place to be).

Comment: Thats what I thought, thank you for the confirmation

Answer (score 4):

**Yes spell strike can be used with whirlwind attack, but spell combat cannot.**

Spell strike allows you to deliver touch spells via your weapon. If you are holding a charge from a touch spell it would apply for as many touches remaining.

http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fz#v5748eaic9r3x

> Yes. For example, if you cast chill touch (which allows multiple touch
>   attacks), you could use spellstrike to cast and deliver the spell
>   through your weapon, and in later weapon attacks you could use your
>   weapon to deliver the remaining spell touch attacks (one spell touch
>   attack per weapon attack).
>
> If you have multiple attacks per round with that weapon (such as from having a BAB of +6 or higher), you can use the weapon to deliver
>   multiple spell touch attacks per round, so long as you have uses of
>   that spell touch attack remaining.
>
> For example, if you are an 8th-level magus (BAB +6/+1) and you cast chill touch, you have up to 8 uses of that spell touch attack. If
>   you make two weapon attacks in a round, you can deliver two spell
>   touch attacks per round (one for each successful weapon attack).

Spell combat says http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-

> **As a full-round action**, he can make all of his attacks with his melee weapon at a –2 penalty and can also cast any spell from the magus spell list with a casting time of 1 standard action (any attack roll made as part of this spell also takes this penalty).

Since spell combat is a full round action and not a full attack action you are not able to cast the spell in the same round that you would use whirlwind attack. The exception being if the spell is a swift action or faster.